# PPTP Clients Connect But Do Not Have Network Access

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, pptp

I have clients that connect to a Window Server 2008 R2 box via PPTP.  They are able to successfully negotiate a connection and receive a local IP address, but are unable to access any internal network resources, nor access the Internet when connected.

There are no error messages or logged messages indicating a problem.

Comment: Try to use static address pool instead of dhcp assignment (Routing and remote access properties - IPv4 Tab)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you haven't configured routing properly in RRAS. There is guidance in the documentation at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled "LAN Routing" in the RRAS configuration?